# How can expo android react native app return a value when opened by an external app?

Tags: react-native, expo, odk

I am using [odk collect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.odk.collect.android&hl=en_US) to fill some forms. I am able to open my app from the odk form with `ex:android.intent.action.VIEW(uri_data='myapp://hello/path')` but I have not been able to respond with parameters.
The odk documentation says that the external app should do the following:

```
Uri uri = ...
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.clipData = ClipData.newRawUri(null, uri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

I am using expo's [IntentLauncher](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v48.0.0/sdk/intent-launcher/#methods) to respond, but I always get a "No Activity found to handle Intent" response.
);

I've been doing:

```js
await startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW',
      {
        extra: { my_variable: 'my_response' },
        flags: 1,
      }
```